# Invalid plist error

Tags: macos, launchd

I'me getting `Invalid property list` when trying `launchctl load -w /Users/open/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.inMemTask14.plist` for this .plist:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.apple.inMemTask14</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/Users/open/Library/Containers/.heheosx/MacOSHighSierra.py</string>
        </array>
        <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>300</integer>  
        <true/>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

What is wrong with my list that I get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last but third line, `<true/>` value has no corresponding key.

Review the entry and make necessary correction.